# Mysql 5 Percentile rank is too slow

Tags: mysql

The following Mysql works and compiles correctly to calculate percentile rank in mysql 5, however its really slow. Once i do a few more joins it ends up being about 1.5 seconds. I think I may be doing this in an inefficient way. Any ideas of how i can make this execute faster. (i know mysql 8 can do this better but current db is what it is.

```
Select ZZ.id,ZZ.symbol,

round(100*(ZZ.count-ZZ.rank1+1)/ZZ.count,0) AS newexample1_prcnt,


round(100*(ZZ2.count-ZZ2.rank2+1)/ZZ2.count,0) AS newexample2_prcnt


FROM
(
Select t.id, t.symbol AS symbol ,max_date as example1date,t.v AS example1, @curRank := @curRank +1 AS rank1, 

(Select count(t.symbol) as total
from (SELECT @CountcurRank := 0) rank1, tbl_market_example1 t
inner join
(SELECT t.symbol,MAX(`t`) as max_date, t.v
FROM  tbl_market_example1 t
WHERE t.v>0
GROUP BY t.symbol)a
on a.symbol = t.symbol and a.max_date = t.t ORDER BY example1 DESC) AS Count  
        
from (SELECT @curRank := 0) rank1, tbl_market_example1 t
inner join
(SELECT t.id, t.symbol,MAX(`t`) as max_date, t.v
FROM  tbl_market_example1 t
WHERE t.v>0
GROUP BY t.symbol) a on a.symbol = t.symbol and a.max_date = t.t ORDER BY example1 DESC) ZZ

LEFT JOIN
(
Select t.symbol AS symbol ,max_date as example2date,t.v AS example2, @curRank2 := @curRank2 + 1 AS rank2,
(Select count(t.symbol) as total
from (SELECT @CountcurRank2 := 0) rank2, tbl_example2 t
inner join
(SELECT t.symbol,MAX(`t`) as max_date, t.v
FROM  tbl_example2 t
WHERE t.v>0
GROUP BY t.symbol)a
on a.symbol = t.symbol and a.max_date = t.t ORDER BY example2 DESC) AS Count    
    
from (SELECT @curRank2 := 0) rank2, tbl_example2 t
inner join
(SELECT t.symbol,MAX(`t`) as max_date, t.v
FROM  tbl_example2 t
WHERE t.v>0
GROUP BY t.symbol)a
on a.symbol = t.symbol and a.max_date = t.t ORDER BY example2 DESC
) ZZ2

ON ZZ.symbol = ZZ2.symbol
```

[EXPLAIN SELECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx0Vr.png)

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7kfu.png)

Comment: If you're going to ask a sql query performance question, you should at the very least include table structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`) and the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: oh ye, first time on here. here is the EXPLAIN SELECT

Comment: ive also added the table structure if that helps?

Comment: To be of more value please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE (for each table used); with this information, we will see where you have indexes or know that indexes are MISSING, as documented in the EXPLAIN.  Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the full answer, but here goes.

I think this has a serious problem:

```
SELECT  t.symbol, MAX(`t`) as max_date, t.v
    FROM  tbl_market_example1 t
    WHERE  t.v>0
    GROUP BY  t.symbol
```

See discussions about "only_full_group_by".  My point is that `t.v` will not necessarily be the value for which `max(t)` occurred.

Instead of `COUNT(x)`, use `COUNT(*)` -- unless you actually need to check that `x IS NOT NULL`.

`ORDER BY example1 DESC` seems to be irrelevant since it is on a `SELECT` that returns a single row.

`CountcurRank` seems to be unused.

Try doing the task using a few `TEMPORARY TABLEs`.  Add to each the appropriate index.  (This may not help the speed, but it may help you to better organize the flow.).

If the pair `(symbol, t)` is unique, consider getting rid of `id` and change to `PRIMARY KEY(symbol, t)`.  (But, since `t` seems to be a "time", there may be dups?)  If not, add this composite index:

```
INDEX(symbol, t)
```

MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.3 have `PERCENTILE` functions and `WITH` built-in, but they may not be any faster.  At some point ih the future of MySQL, your use of `@x := ...` will be disallowed, thereby forcing you to perform the task in a different way.  (I would guess that you are using 5.7 now?)

It may help to provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see the PK and datatypes.